# how to access postgresql database view using strongloop

Tags: postgresql, strongloop

Please help in accessing postgresql database view using strongloop.
im able to access table

```
{"name": "test", 
   "options": {
      "idInjection": false,
      "postgresql": {
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "test_data_v"
      }
   }, 
   "properties": {

      "assetid": {
        "type": "String",
        "required": false,
        "length": 40,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "id": 1,
        "postgresql": {
          "columnName": "asset_id",
          "dataType": "character varying",
          "dataLength": 40,
          "dataPrecision": null,
          "dataScale": null,
          "nullable": "YES"
        }
      }  
    }}
```

in same way please suggest me how to access view
Thanks
Divya

Answer (score 0):

> I am not installed postgresql but I tried in mysql, Its working fine.
>   IN your model you can do directly see this Example

In database I have created view that is

```
CREATE VIEW shareviews AS
SELECT id,name
FROM share where id = 1;
```

> In model you can call viewname directly like this example

```
module.exports = function(Share) {

    var server = require('../../server/server');
    var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL; // use  server.dataSources.postgres;

    Share.list = function(optionalparam, cb) {     

      var sql = 'select * from shareviews';
      ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
      {
      if(err) return err;
      console.log(err);
      console.log("data",data);
        cb(null, data);
      });

    }

    Share.remoteMethod(
        'list', 
        {
          accepts: {arg: 'param', type: 'string'},
          returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
          http: {path: '/list', verb: 'get'}
        }
    );


};
```

> You need to set data source in datasource.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "postgres": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "database": "postgres",
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "*******",
    "name": "postgres",
    "connector": "postgresql"
  }
}
```

> Then in model-config.json you need to assign data source name to each
>   model.

That is

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "yourmodelname": {
    "dataSource": "postgres",
    "public": true
  },
  "yourmodelname": {
    "dataSource": "postgres",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

> then you can access database in you model.js or Rest call(example localhost:3000/explorer) For Example my
>   model name Grocerylist

```
module.exports = function(Grocerylist) {
  Grocerylist.beforeRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
    var req = context.req;
    req.body.date = Date.now();
    req.body.shopperId = req.accessToken.userId;
    next();
  });

  Grocerylist.complete = function(shopperId, cb) {
    Grocerylist.find({
      where: {
        purchased:false,
        shopperId: shopperId,
      }
    }, function(err, list) {
        var response;
        if (typeof list === 'undefined' || list.length === 0) {
          response = "All done shopping!"
        }
        else {
          response = "Shopping is not done.";
        }
        cb(null, response);
    });
  };
  Grocerylist.remoteMethod(
    'complete',
    {
      accepts: {
        arg: 'shopperId', type: 'string'
      },
      http: {
        path: '/complete',
        verb: 'get'
      },
      returns: {
        arg: 'complete',
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Please help in accessing postgresql database view using strongloop.
im able to access table

Comment: im able to access table by adding table in model.json using the below code. please help to access view from database in the same way

Comment: {"name": "test", 
   "options": {
      "idInjection": false,
      "postgresql": {
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "test_data_v"
      }
   }, 
   "properties": {

      "assetid": {
        "type": "String",
        "required": false,
        "length": 40,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "id": 1,
        "postgresql": {
          "columnName": "asset_id",
          "dataType": "character varying",
          "dataLength": 40,
          "dataPrecision": null,
          "dataScale": null,
          "nullable": "YES"
        }
      }  
    }}

Comment: supervisor running without clustering (unsupervised)
module.js:489
    throw err;

Comment: SyntaxError: D:\GEGDC\MD98012\DB CONNECTIN SYSTEM STATUS\hitsyss\server\common\models\iso_serverscope_view.json: Unexpected token v
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:486:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Comment: at Module.module.__proto__.require (C:\Users\md98012\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_mod
ules\strong-agent\lib\agent.js:185:42)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at loadModelDefinition (D:\GEGDC\MD98012\DB CONNECTIN SYSTEM STATUS\hitsyss\server\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:440:20)
    at D:\GEGDC\MD98012\DB CONNECTIN SYSTEM STATUS\hitsyss\server\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:336:21
    at Array.forEach (native)

Comment: "isocmdbviwe": {
    "dataSource": "dev_corp_it",
    "public": true
  }

Comment: "dev_corp_it": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 5432,
    "database": "corp_it",
    "username": "test",
    "password": "testt",
    "name": "dev_corp_it",
      "debug": true,
   "connector": "postgresql"
  }

Comment: module.exports = function(isocmdbviwe) { 
       var isocmdc = require('../../server/server/datasources.json');
     var ds = isocmdc.dataSources.dev_corp_it;  
     isocmdbviwe.list = function(optionalparam, cb) {     
       var sql = 'select * from test';
       ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
       {if(err) return err;
       console.log("data",data);
         cb(null, data); }); }
     isocmdbviwe.remoteMethod(
         'list', { returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
           http: {path: '/list', verb: 'get'}
         } );};

Comment: Riax thanx for your quick respone.. i have added the above code 1st once is mode-config.json 2nd databaource.json 3rd model.js

Comment: SyntaxError: D:test\setrver\common\models\iso_serverscope_view.json: Unexpected token v
at Object.parse
at Object.Module._extensions..json module.js
at Module.load module.js
at Function.Module._load module.js
at Module.require module.js
at Module.module.__proto__.require C:\Users\md98012\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_moules\strong-agent\lib\agent.js:185:42
at require module.js:384:17
at loadModelDefinition D:test\server\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js
at D:test\server\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js
at Array.forEach

Comment: var isocmdc = require('../../server/server');  try this

Comment: Riaz, i have added  
var isocmdc = require('../../server/server');

Comment: its syntax error. I think if you add any comments remove it. in your datasource or modelconfig.Json check once all the things

Comment: otherwise create new  sample app and try.

Comment: im able to access table by adding below code in model,js with same database.json and model-config.json

Comment: {"name": "isocmdbviwe", 
   "options": {
      "idInjection": false,
      "postgresql": {
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "mstr_invnt_tech"
      }
   }, 
   "properties": {
       
      "assetid": {
        "type": "String",
        "required": false,
        "length": 50,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "id": 1,
        "postgresql": {
          "columnName": "asset_id",
          "dataType": "character varying",
          "dataLength": 50,
          "dataPrecision": null,
          "dataScale": null,
          "nullable": "YES"
        }    }
    }}

Comment: but im not able to access view

Comment: Unexpected token v
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:486:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Comment: did you try new sample application?

Comment: riaz i have installed npm install pg pg-native.. but im nt getting how to start nthat application

Comment: do you have basic knowledge in strongloop ?

Comment: yes , in my project im using loop-back-mysql perviously

Comment: now i need to access view from postgresql im facing issue there

Comment: look this demo application,  https://github.com/0candy/grocerylist .  . I am not having knowledge in postgresql

Comment: Riaz, thanks for your help but in that application they are not exeguting any queries